# css module not being read: Syntax Error

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules

Here is a component importing css...

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './sample.css';

class Index extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <div>

                <div className="${styles.bodywrap}"></div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

My stylesheet `sample.css` is the following...

```
.bodywrap {
    color:red;
}
```

But when I run the web app I get the following error...

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/tutorHub/components/index_components/sample.c
ss: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | .bodywrap {
    | ^
  2 |   color:red;
  3 | }
```

I followed the instuctions to setup css modules, so my webpack.config looks as follows...

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: 'index.js'
     },
    module: {
         loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query:{
                     presets: ['es2015','react'],
                }
            },
            {
         test: /\.css/,
         loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
      }


        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
     ]
 };
```

Any idea why my CSS is not being read properly? Do I need something to convert the code so it is recognized properly?

EDIT

I think its important to node that I'm rendering the component above through the server using node js...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var App = React.createFactory(require('../components/index'));
var MasterLayout = React.createFactory(require('../master/links'));

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({}));
    var styles = reactDom.renderToString(MasterLayout({}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml, links: styles});

});
```

Can this be interfering with the css?

Comment: try install `style-loader` and then add it to `ExtractTextPlugin.extract` like this `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **webpack.config.js** add this loader :-

```
{
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
  ]
}
```

Add in your component add this :-

```
   import 'yourPath.css';
```

for use  classes of this css file just write

```
<div className="yourClassName" />
```

Comment: Please read up on how to format your posts, especially the code parts.

Comment: why did you add the font loader?